# Android studio/AdMob/Firebase leave banner for premium

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I'm ready to publish my Android app on play store, and I've added banners for some revenue.
I'd like to know if can I make app purchase for leave the banners and give a "free banners" version of my app.
I've searched a lot but I've found anything.

Comment: Why the firebase tag?

Comment: Yes, majority of apps implement such feature. You need to integrate with Google In-app purchase library https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html , once you get response from Google for successful purchase you need to write if() conditions around you banner to not show ads if user made purchase

Answer (score 0):

You have two option :

1. Make two separate app one with Ad and another is paid app(user need to pay before download) that is without Ad.
2. Put Ad inside your App and when user is in your App, prompt dialog to pay some amount to remove Ad otherwise user have to use your App with all your Ad.